# What does this Visual Studio icon mean?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012

When I opened up a VS solution this morning, the icons for files in the data folder had changed. They normally look like (a slightly different folder):

[image]

They now look like:

[image]

What does that icon mean, and how could I possibly find this out (apart from posting this question, hopefully)??

Motivation: The issue is that these files are used as upload files in web tests, and are now all failing with "Request failed: Could not find a part of the path" *even when I add them to the path, and I am absolutely certain that the paths are correct* (copied the path from the file properties).

Anything at all that I could try would be hugely appreciated.

Comment: The dotted line outline means they're not part of the project - you need to include them back in the project (you should be able to right-click on the file and select include).

Comment: @Tim why not turn that into an answer?

Comment: Thanks guys, I'll wait a second to see if anyone can help with why I'd be getting the request failed error even when they were re-added, then if there's nothing on that will mark one of these as the answer

Answer (score 5):

It means that the files or folders are out of `project`.

To add on the project, right click over the item and on the context menu click on `Include on project`.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

The dotted outline means they're not part of the project - you need to include them back in the project.  You should be able to do this by right-clicking on the file and selecting include from the context menu.

Here's a screenshot to illustrate (note that you can also add entire folders, as in my screenshot below):

[image]